# Magento site takes too long to load

Tags: magento2, websites

My magento production site takes too long to load. How can this issue be resolved from magento side?

Answer (score 1):

**Speed Up Your Magento eCommerce Site Reference Links :-**

> https://servebolt.com/articles/speed-up-magento-2-in-7-easy-steps/
>
> https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/magento-2-performance-optimization/
>
> https://www.icecubedigital.com/blog/how-to-speed-up-magento-2-website/
>
> https://www.goivvy.com/blog/speed-up-magento